# Extracting the lower and greater instances of Comparable objects into dedicated variables

Tags: java, java-8

I am not sure if this is a dumb or trivial question but I have been looking for a while and I can't get to an answer.

Throught my project the following block is repeated quite often:

```
void someMethod(Timeslot t1, Timeslot t2) {
    Timeslot start, end;
    if (t1.compareTo(t2) >= 0) {
        start = t1;
        end = t2;
    } else {
        start = t2;
        end = t1;
    }
    // do something with start and end
}
```

`t1` and `t2` usually are the limits of a range but the method doesn't require the first argument to be the lower limit and the second to be the higher, so I just do what you can see above to figure out which limit is which, very trivial.

I just want to be DRY, so I wonder if there is some method or some way to do that in a more concise way, probably some of the Java 8 new features let us do this. Something like this?

```
void someMethod(Timeslot t1, Timeslot t2) {
    Timeslot t1, t2;
    assignLimits(t1, t2, Timeslot::compareTo); // does this exist?
}
```

Maybe what I am asking is absolutetly trivial and I am missing something obvious. In this case, please help me see this. Or maybe, there's simply nothing wrong with repeating the original chunk.

Comment: Write something yourself that returns a `Pair` with a `min` and `max`.

Comment: Or `sort` a `LinkedList` of your two elements and `getFirst` and `getLast`. Or a `List` and `get(0)` and `get(1)`.

Comment: AFAIK Java doesn't have pairs natively.

Comment: It does not. Write your own.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will definetly have them in mind but I was looking for more of a native, built-in solution rather, maybe lambdas would fit the case?

Comment: Nothing in the JDK exists that will achieve your entire use case. Lambda expressions are just a syntax tool. If you meant `Stream`, it has a `mix` and `max` method, but you'll need to create two `Stream` instances as they can not be consumed more than once. Better to just sort a list.

Comment: Or create your own `min()` and `max()` methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is correct.  Nothing in the JDK will solve this all by itself.  Writing your own `MinAndMax` class is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to provide such a utility function, as you can’t pass two local variables by reference and there is no way of returning two values from a method to be assigned to two variables. All attempts to work-around this limitations will be considered overkill for just swapping two local variables and thus not be used by most developers.

For completeness, here some alternatives:

1. initialize as given, swap only when necessary

   ```
   void someMethod(Timeslot t1, Timeslot t2) {
       Timeslot start=t1, end=t2;
       if (t1.compareTo(t2) < 0) {
           start = t2;
           end = t1;
       }
       // do something with start and end
   }
   ```

   Since `t1` and `t2` are still available, we can use them to swap without a temporary variable here. We could also reuse `t1` as start and `t2` as end, so we don’t need the initial assignment, then, however, in that case swapping needs a temporary variable, so the readability doesn’t improve.
2. Via helper methods:

   ```
   static final <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(T t1, T t2) {
       return t1.compareTo(t2)>=0? t1: t2;
   }
   static final <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T min(T t1, T t2) {
       return t1.compareTo(t2)<0? t1: t2;
   }
   void someMethod2(Timeslot t1, Timeslot t2) {
       Timeslot start=min(t1, t2), end=max(t1, t2);
       // do something with start and end
   }
   ```

   The methods can be re-used. Note that the `min` function intentionally has a different behavior regarding equal elements, to avoid getting two identical objects, if two distinct object, which are equal according their natural order, are passed into the method. The obvious disadvantage is requiring two comparisons.
3. Via Stream:

   ```
   void someMethod3(Timeslot t1, Timeslot t2) {
       Timeslot[] range=Stream.of(t1, t2).sorted().toArray(Timeslot[]::new);
       // do something with range[0] and range[1]
   }
   ```

   This is exemplary for the family of similar solutions, e.g. `Timeslot[] range={ t1, t2}; Arrays.sort(range);`, etc. They are the most concise solutions, but requires to express the two values as an array, demonstrating the problem of pre-built functions which can’t return multiple values (without using an object/array).